# Draw circle on depth data from Kinect V2

Tags: c++, kinect, kinect-sdk, direct2d

I am a beginner in programming and have been going through the DepthBasics-D2D sample in the Kinect2 SDK. I am interested in getting depth value of a single point and want to draw that point on the output window with the depth image for better visualization. Something like a red dot on the pixel location [x,y] of which I am getting the depth value. How would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: I didn't work with the c++ samples. However .... the depth data of [x,y] coordinate is equivalent to `depthDataArray[index = y*512 + x]` where `depthDataArray` is the array where depth frame data is saved.

Comment: Also [this tutorial](http://pterneas.com/2014/02/20/kinect-for-windows-version-2-color-depth-and-infrared-streams/) may help you.

Comment: Yes I already have the value of the depth on that pixel. I want to draw a dot on the pixel location in the output window.

Comment: will a c# example help you?

Comment: I am mostly comfortable with C++ but yes it would help.